# RangeError with Meteor and Twilio Client

Tags: meteor, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I am trying to set up outgoing calls on Meteor through Twilio. To do that, I have a method on the backend to generate a capability token.

When I try to actually initiate the call, I get a `RangeError` that nobody else seems to have experienced.

```
// get capability token
Meteor.call('twilioCallToken', function(err, capToken) {
  if (capToken) {
    Twilio.Device.setup(capToken, { closeProtection: true }); // RangeError thrown on this line
  }
});
```

The exact error is:

```
Exception in delivering result of invoking 'twilioCallToken': RangeError:  Maximum call stack size exceeded
at a.addCommand.(anonymous function) [as setup] (https://static.twilio.com/libs/twiliojs/1.2/twilio.min.js:1:411)
at a.addCommand.(anonymous function) [as setup] (https://static.twilio.com/libs/twiliojs/1.2/twilio.min.js:1:411)
at a.addCommand.(anonymous function) [as setup] (https://static.twilio.com/libs/twiliojs/1.2/twilio.min.js:1:411)
at a.addCommand.(anonymous function) [as setup] (https://static.twilio.com/libs/twiliojs/1.2/twilio.min.js:1:411)
at a.addCommand.(anonymous function) [as setup] (https://static.twilio.com/libs/twiliojs/1.2/twilio.min.js:1:411)
at a.addCommand.(anonymous function) [as setup] (https://static.twilio.com/libs/twiliojs/1.2/twilio.min.js:1:411)
at a.addCommand.(anonymous function) [as setup] (https://static.twilio.com/libs/twiliojs/1.2/twilio.min.js:1:411)
at a.addCommand.(anonymous function) [as setup] (https://static.twilio.com/libs/twiliojs/1.2/twilio.min.js:1:411)
at a.addCommand.(anonymous function) [as setup] (https://static.twilio.com/libs/twiliojs/1.2/twilio.min.js:1:411)
at a.addCommand.(anonymous function) [as setup] (https://static.twilio.com/libs/twiliojs/1.2/twilio.min.js:1:411)
```

Comment: Where and how is your `twilioCallToken` method written? Did you check what's in `err`?

Comment: The method works. `err` is undefined and `token` shows the capability token.